# MVC5 Radio Button Instant Hide/Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I used to use this in Web Form development through the id and name of the input radio button, but can't seem to get it in MVC5, could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

On a radio button (part of the model) selection, depending which button, I want another text box to appear (within a div).

**View:**

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
                  <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <p>AS Number Type</p>
                        <span>
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NumberType, "Odd", true)Odd
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NumberType, "Even", false)Even
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @if (Model.NumberType == true)
                {
                    <div id="OddOrEven">
                        <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                            <div class="ui-block-a">
                                <span>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Reason)
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/maintainscroll.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[Value='Odd']").click(function () {
                var test = $(this).val();
                $("#OddOrEven").show();
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Comment: `"input[Value='Odd']"` this does'nt selected the element?

Comment: It's not working for me :(

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what doesn't really works. Won't you post the result html generated from razor?

Comment: What @purplesmurf said worked, guess the model was blocking the js or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NumberType, "Odd", true)Odd
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NumberType, "Even", false)Even

<div id="OddOrEven">
  <div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
      <span>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Reason)
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $("#OddOrEven").hide();
  $("input[name='NumberType']").on("change", function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Odd") {
      $("#OddOrEven").show();
    }
  }):
</script>
```

Basically, grab the change event of your radio button group by the input's name, rather than the value.  The issue with using the value is that if you have multiple radio button groups on the same view, and they each have the same value pairs (ie: true/false), then your view would not know which radio group to select.  Using name is the proper way to go.

Comment: Nice, gets rid of my inline css

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `@if` surrounding the div, set the div css class to hidden on page load, then your button will work, however clicking off of it will still leave it there, add to the javascript to hide the textbox again.

So remove that `@if` change your div to `<div id="OddOrEven" style="display:none">` and the below within your `script`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[Value='Odd']").click(function () {
                $("#OddOrEven").show();
            });
            $("input[Value='Even']").click(function () {
                $("#OddOrEven").hide();
            });
        });
```

Comment: You were first, and right, but Eckert's is better and cleaner